# Very Basic 555 Timer oscillator not working

Tags: oscillator, 555

I've been trying to make an LED blink. My first approaches were without the 555 timer, and they were unsuccessful. I decided to make an Astable multivibrator circuit. I'm using an NE555, and I'm using the circuit on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stN-ZzHfiO4). For R1, I used a 680ohm resistor, and for R2 I've used 1k, 10k, 100k, 500k, 1M ohm resistors, and none of them have proven succesful. For my capacitor, I'm using a 100uF capacitor. I've tried 1uF and 1000uF aswell. Please help!

Comment: Most likely wire contact or wiring error.

Comment: Can you add a schematic to your question, there is a built in tool?

Comment: If you're working from a design that has been shown to work and yours isn't working you need to show us some info about _your_ circuit.

Comment: Maybe the LED was burnt out from putting in backwards at >5V

Comment: Are you sure you've got the capacitor connected with the correct polarity?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, try following a schematic rather than a youtube tutorial showing a breadboard. There is a good chance you may have wired something incorrectly.

A 555 timer in an astable configuration would look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3qj4f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using this, you should be able to place your components on a breadboard, following the schematic closely. I assume you know the internal connections of a breadboard, but just in case, here is a diagram:

[image]

If you change the values of R1/R2 or C1 then you will be able to vary the frequency. Or stick a potentiometer in the place of R2.

This link [HERE](http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/555-astable-calculator) will be able to help you calculate which values to use for your desired frequency.

If you wanted to work it out yourself, you could use the forumula:

f= 1.44/(R1+2R2)C

Although I have found that to be a tad off sometimes! But it gives you a ballpark idea as real world electronics will never be exact!

So, basically, take it apart and rebuild it, this time following a schematic!

P.S make sure you have a working LED!

Comment: Thanks for this! However, I found another circuit that only requires one capacitor and I got that one to work. Thanks though :)

Comment: No worries. Glad you got it working!